# Mcrypt enabled and Laravel still complains

Tags: mcrypt, laravel-5

I am on OS X 10.9, using MAMP. I have mcrypt installed and it is enabled when I look at php -i. I am running the composer via php through composer.phar. Getting:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v5.0.5 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.4 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.3 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.2 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.1 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.0 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.0.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.0.0, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5].
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late.. but if you still have the problem, it's certainly because of your php version ..

Composer use the system version and mcrypt module may not be installed for that version. So check the version that your system using and do what you can to choose the "correct" php.

For example change your PATH env variable ;p

Best regards,